# AutoCompleteTextview doesn't show dropdown suggestion for first character entry

Tags: java, android, arrays, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` `searchFriends` and a `String[] usernames= {"Lex","Lincoln","Luther"}` that I get from a database.

Problem: The first time I type in the letter "L" in the `AutoCompleteTextView`, no suggestions are shown. If I press backspace to remove the "L" and then retype "L" again, then "Lex", "Lincoln" and "Luther" are suggested. I want suggestions to be shown the first time something is entered.

```
public class SearchFriendsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Firebase userbase;

AutoCompleteTextView searchFriends;

ArrayAdapter adapter;

char firstChar;
String url, listOfusers, inputUsername, userss;
String[] usersArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_friends);

    searchFriends= (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.searchFriends);

    searchFriends.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        private Timer timer = new Timer();
        private final long DELAY = 1000; // milliseconds

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {                   
                }


        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            timer.cancel();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(
                    new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    if (s.length() == 0) {
                                        firstChar = '.';
                                    } else {
                                        if (firstChar == s.charAt(0)) {
                                            aVoid();
                                        } else {
                                            firstChar = s.charAt(0);
                                            url = @string/databaseString + firstChar.toString() + "/";
                                            userbase = new Firebase(url);
                                            createArray();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    DELAY
            );

        }
    });

}

public void createArray() {
    userbase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            listOfusers = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
            userss = listOfusers.replaceAll("=.*?\\}", "").replace("{", "").replace("}", "").replace(", ", ",");
            usersArray = userss.split(",");

            aVoid();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public void aVoid() {
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.suggestion_dropdown_item, usersArray);
    searchFriends.setThreshold(1);
    searchFriends.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this problem by replacing the text with the same text in the edittext a moment after the adapter is created:

```
public void replaceAllText() {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    final long DELAY = 300; // milliseconds

    timer.cancel();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(
            new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            String replace = searchFriends.getText().toString();
                            searchFriends.setText(replace);
                            searchFriends.setSelection(searchFriends.getText().length());
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            DELAY
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the entire list in the adapter, it's as easy as this:

```
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Filterable adapter = (Filterable) searchFriends.getAdapter();
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
    }
```

Comment: Oops. Updated answer.

Comment: i get this nullpointer error   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.widget.Filter android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getFilter()' on a null object reference

Comment: Ah. Okay. So this changes your code a little bit, because what you are trying to do now is load new Firebase data every time the user types a key.  That's not very efficient.  What you should do is first create the `ArrayAdapter` with the data from Firebase and then as the user types, the `ArrayAdapter` will filter that data and update the autocomplete dropdown, so you don't need to access Firebase constantly.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the code inside `onTextChanged` into `afterTextChange` because in `onTextChanged`, the text inside the `AutoCompleteTextView` is not yet set to it evertime you input a character. So on your first input (ex. "L"), the value of `AutoCompleteTextView.getText().toString;` is still `null`, that is why you have your problems.

`onTextChanged` is commonly used to capture the Key pressed to perform checking or validation before appending it to previous value of the `AutoCompleteEditText`.

`aftetTextChange` on the otherhand is fired (as the name implies) after the previous value of the `AutoCompleteEditText` is changed. So your code is best put inside `afterTextChanged` rather than in `onTextChanged`.

Comment: Tried it, but it made no difference

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to AutoCompleteTextView

```
android:completionThreshold="1"
```